# Implementing jquery UI autocomplete to show suggestions when you type “@” in jquery.wysiwyg rich text editor

Tags: jquery-ui, text, autocomplete, editor

I have similar requirementas of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972958/implementing-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-show-suggestions-when-you-type/5973017#5973017) , like i have to autosuggestion when user types in @ in jquery.wysiwyg  rich text editor , the above code link code is working fine for input type text  and textarea but not working for rich text editor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.css" type="text/css" />
    <script>


    $(function() {
$('#tags').wysiwyg({
autoGrow: true,
maxHeight: 250,
focusEditor: true
});
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/@\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

$("#tags")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term,
            results = [];

        /* If the user typed an "@": */
        if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
            term = extractLast(request.term);
            /* If they've typed anything after the "@": */
            if (term.length > 0) {
                results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, term);
            /* Otherwise, tell them to start typing! */
            } else {
                results = ['Start typing...'];
            }
        }
        /* Call the callback with the results: */
        response(results);
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("");
        return false;
    }
});

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <textarea id="tags" ></textarea>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>The Autocomplete widgets provides suggestions while you type into the field. Here the suggestions are tags for programming languages, give "ja" (for Java or JavaScript) a try.</p>
<p>The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
<script>


</script>
</html>
```

so if i remove

```
$('#tags').wysiwyg({
autoGrow: true,
maxHeight: 250,
focusEditor: true
});
```

this code in  textarea it is working but not in rich text editor. So please guide me so that i can  achive same functionality in rich text editor.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually working on the exact same problem right now. My first clue is that the textbox in the wysiwyg is part of an iframe. If there's no way to have this display inline, it may be a dead-end.

Comment: That rich text editor won't work without an iframe, so it may be impossible to do what you're trying to do.

I'm going to try and start again, using the editors referred to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914510/wysiwyg-editor-without-iframe