# Twitter/Facebook @mention functionality with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter, hashtag

I'm trying to implement an @mention system in an application I'm building and am running into some difficulties.

My initial approach is this:

1. Create two hidden inputs after the textarea/input being @mentionified. The first will hold the text being searched for (for the autocomplete). The second will hold found mentions in the form @[objectId:text].
2. This is harder to put into practice than one would think. When someone presses the @ symbol I need to start feeding the subsequent text into the autocomplete. I need to only get the text between the @ symbol and the cursor. What if they click the cursor to some other part of the input to edit something, then come back to edit the @ text. The script needs to be smart enough to only search the autocomplete when the user is updating the text right after the @ symbol.

Thoughts on the best way to implement this? Is there a plugin out there that already does this?

Comment: @Marc: Check out jQueryUI autocomplete's multiple values demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple. Does this help at all?

Comment: Hmm I have played with it before. I don't think it really applies in this case but thanks anyhow.

Comment: @Marc: How does it not apply? Imagine using an `@` instead of a `,` like in the example.

Comment: Because it does not allow for the use case I'm after. With it, there is no way to allow a user to type "Here is some text @andrew and @marc". There are other problems, but that's the largest one. Unless I'm missing something here, I would love to use it if it could be adapted but my gut feeling is it would be a more work than it's worth.

Comment: @Marc: You're right about that--Here's an answer I gave awhile back that might get you started (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5972958/497356). The trouble is coming back to edit the text after the '@', but it might get you on the right track at least...

Comment: That absolutely looks helpful. I'll take a look, modify it as needed, and post back a solution if I find one. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I use this: https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input

Here is a [demo](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/). I think it's helpful for you.

EDIT:

The above plugin isn't maintained anymore. This plugin (by [Ivan Virabyan](https://github.com/ivirabyan)) is a fork with some improvements: https://github.com/ivirabyan/jquery-mentions

Comment: Its buggy as hell. A lot of times tagged user names are not rendered properly after moving to next line.

Comment: do you have a great alternative?

Comment: This http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/ at least does what it says. Thought it is compatible with jquery 1.8 only. No rendering problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550232/jquery-mention-input-not-rendering-properly .

Comment: @Terminal I made an alternative where I tried to fix all bugs known to me. Check it out https://github.com/ivirabyan/jquery-mentions

Comment: @IvanVirabyan I checked it. Its working properly only in chrome. Css is not showing up as expected in IE(9), opera(12.4) and firefox 25.0. Firefox only have problem with input box

Comment: @IvanVirabyan nice fork! Is there an external function to insert a tagged element into the textarea?

Comment: @Chandrew, I've added support for this. Use it like this: `$('textarea').mentionsInput('append', {name: 'John', uid: 'user-123'})`

Comment: @Terminal I fixed these issues

Comment: @IvanVirabyan Please fix the "Mentioning Multiple Users with Same name"(Different id). Other than this is good :)

Comment: @Naveen-நவீன் it doesn't have any issues with this. The only question is how those users can be distinguished visually?

Comment: @IvanVirabyan I Have these issues right now, May i know when u going to fix this? If i set "allowRepeat: true" means i can mention multiple with same name but that background is misalign.
1.https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input/issues/104   
2.https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input/issues/118

Comment: @Naveen-நவீன் this plugin is not maintained by me, my own implementation is here https://github.com/ivirabyan/jquery-mentions

Comment: @IvanVirabyan Ohh k, Will try this. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanVirabyan I have tried your plugin, Its working Awe. I need two things to be done, 1. Option for mention one user once per textarea, 2. That suggestion box is appearing outside textarea, if it is display in cursor position its will be good.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with this myself and ended up writing a solution that uses a hidden field to store the user_id within the full context of the post:

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/

Answer (score 2):

I'm a couple of years late, and it looks as thought you may have avoided "recreating the wheel", but I thought I'd add my two cents in case you (OP), or anyone else, wants to try their hand implementing this functionality from scratch.

A "mention"-management utility has 3 components:

1. **Autocomplete module**: The component responsible for procuring and displaying the set of items that can be used to create a mention, given a string.
2. **Mention tracking module**: The component responsible for keeping track of mention-associated data; at the bare minimum the location, as well as the superficial and substantive (if existent) values of each mention should be tracked throughout all modifications of the text of the input element to which the utility is affixed.
3. **Mention visual differentiation module**: The component responsible for differentiating mention text from the rest of the text in the input element to which the utility is affixed

Given this breakdown of such a utility, it should become clear that the *first* and *second steps* in original post are ones that can be taken in the implementation of the *mention management* and *autocomplete* modules, respectively.

Delving further in to the implementation of the 3 modules, in plain English, would be tedious; its much better to look at code! Fortunately, I've made a solution, [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator), that is robust (more so than all the other solutions suggested here), well-structured, easy to follow, and copiously commented. So its worth a look at whether you just want an out-of-the box solution, or reference material to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the jquery.mentionsInput plugin. It supports @mention tagging just like on facebook, complete with avatars and either local or ajax data.

http://podio.github.com/jquery-mentions-input/

Comment: According to the author it is not longer maintained.