# jquery ui autocomplete suggestion are not closing after entering space between typed words

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi I have previously opened this thread  [How to tag users in feed like Facebook or Twitter does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848337/how-to-tag-users-in-feed-like-facebook-or-twitter-does). I am working with  jquery autocomplete & so far I have [this](http://pastie.org/2754819) code with me.

Now when I am entering @user-name the suggestions are appearing. But when I hit spacebar the suggestions still remain there. Ideally suggestions should disappear as I hit space bar as we experience in facebook. Please help me to get the ideal behaviour. Thank you!

Comment: I'm actually not seeing that with Facebook... It looks like when you hit space sometimes new suggestions come up. Additionally, with the code you're using options should disappear *unless* there's a space in the autocomplete option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code to add one more line to `else` scope on line number 45

```
else
{
    $( "#birds" ).blur().focus();
    return false;
}
```

I'm sure it will fix the problem.