# Possible to use jQuery Auto Suggest for a Twitter Mention like suggestions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autosuggest

With Twitter, when you type a tweet, anytime you type @ it triggers an autosuggest to quickly enter a twitter handle. You can do @ at the beginning of a tweet in the middle and multiple times.

Can jQuery AutoSuggest handle this? After looking it over it seems like it is good for input fields that just contain the autosuggest value. Not multiple times or in various locations.

Thoughts? Examples? Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI autocomplete? If so, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5972958/497356

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using a textarea, simply put a textarea and bind it a keypress event and listen for @ charCode then fire an AJAX request to show autocomplete box. Consider the following simple demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vmes9/6/

Answer (score 0):

If by *"jQuery AutoSuggest"* you mean [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), and if by *"handle this"* you mean *"serve as a component in an implementation of this"*, then yes, it can :).

A "mention"-management utility has 3 components:

1. **Autocomplete module**: The component responsible for procuring and displaying the set of items that can be used to create a mention, given a string.
2. **Mention tracking module**: The component responsible for keeping track of mention-associated data; at the bare minimum the location, as well as the superficial and substantive (if existent) values of each mention should be tracked throughout all modifications of the text of the input element to which the utility is affixed.
3. **Mention visual differentiation module**: The component responsible for differentiating mention text from the rest of the text in the input element to which the utility is affixed.

Since you asked for an example of such a utility, check out [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator), which actually uses jQuery UI Autocomplete as its autocomplete module. Mentionator is robust, well-structured, easy to follow and copiously commented, so it should be of use to as either an out-of-the box solution, or reference material for a prospective one. It is mantained by *moi*.