# Any jquery plugin like twitter auto completion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do something like twitter. If I type `@`, it will show a list of who I am following,   and then I can select one, insert name to the textarea.

Are there any good plugin for this?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing jquery UI autocomplete to show suggestions when you type "@"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972958/implementing-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-show-suggestions-when-you-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check this solution: http://www.amirharel.com/2011/03/07/implementing-autocomplete-jquery-plugin-for-textarea/