# Getting both @user and #tag using jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been using Andrew Whitaker's code at jsfiddle.net/5xbhY. I was hoping someone could help me make it work for both @user and #tags (they come from different external db's but I should be able to write that part what I am having trouble with is detecting the hash).

```
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ];
    
    var startTyping = "Start typing...";
    
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/@/);
    }
    
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    
    $("#tags")
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term,
                results = [];
            if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                term = extractLast(request.term);
                if (term.length > 0) {
                    results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, term);
                } else {
                    results = [startTyping];
                }
            }
            response(results);
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value !== startTyping) {
                var terms = this.value.split(' ');
                terms.pop();
                terms.push("@" + ui.item.value);
                this.value = terms.join(" ");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Original Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972958/implementing-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-show-suggestions-when-you-type/9189719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BfAtM/181/

Oh, I noticed a bit late I'm responding to a 3 months old question.