# Add attr for AutoSuggest and Trigger @

Tags: jquery, facebook, triggers, attr, autosuggest

I'm trying to make Username with trigger @ and href for username to link to their profilepage.
I just made php script and it works as well, but i don't have to much experience with jQuery, so my problem is that i don't know how to add url for username.

I want that jQuery will activate when a user do type @user..... and when it shows autosuggest, there must be a link, even same for when you are typing @user.., like facebook.
What i did for now is:

```
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $("#username").autocomplete({
        $("#username").attr('href'),
        source: "hassearch.php",
        minLength: 1
    });             

});
```

But it's not totally works, if you can help me how it works in the right way with jQuery, thank you and i can learn a lot about jQuery then!

**Update**: I found a ideal jQuery coding: [Implementing jquery UI autocomplete to show suggestions when you type "@"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972958/implementing-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-show-suggestions-when-you-type) - But my question is now, how can i load php file to get users in database?

I want to load php file in tags:

```
    var availableTags = [--> to load php file <--];

function split(val) {
    return val.split(/@\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

$("#tags")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term,
            results = [];

        /* If the user typed an "@": */
        if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
            term = extractLast(request.term);
            /* If they've typed anything after the "@": */
            if (term.length > 0) {
                results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, term);
            /* Otherwise, tell them to start typing! */
            } else {
                results = ['Start typing...'];
            }
        }
        /* Call the callback with the results: */
        response(results);
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expatiate the solution you've adopted:

The `source` option of jQuery UI Autocomplete is used to specify an array containing the items that are to be displayed in the drop-down list once the widget is triggered. It can be defined as such an array, a function that returns such an array, or a URL to a resource which produces such an array.

If the array which ultimately becomes the value of `source` is empty, the widget won't display a drop-down list. So, defining `source` as a function capable of returning a non-empty array **only when** `@` is entered will make the widget behave as you desire. And since its a function, you can procure the array anyway you like, using any data you'd like, including that procured from an ajax call directed towards a php file ;) .

Check out [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator) if you're looking for an existing product that makes use of such a function in order to provide mention creation and management functionality (a **mention** is a single instance of what you are trying to create with Autocomplete), as well as helpful auxiliary features. Its maintained by yours truly :) .