# modification in @mention autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have seen your this quetion.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972958/implementing-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-show-suggestions-when-you-type
```

and see answers comment but I want to modify the display of selected element. If I want to set remove button means cross mark on selected Item then from where I have to change code?

like if by mistake I select "PHP" then want cross icon on each selected elemt.

I have seen this example :

`http://jsfiddle.net/5xbhY/`

please reply me @Andrew Whitaker your answer and help are awesome...

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can search him _Andrew Whitaker_ in the users tab above.

Comment: thanks but how can we directly ask that user???